# trying to root, SU shows connection timed out

Tags: root-access

I am trying to root my device using this article: [ZTE Maven root (Z831)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/zte-maven-root-z831.3640221/).

When running the command `su` under adb shell, I get an error:

```
[-] Connection to ui timed out
```

Can you please help and advise?

Android 6.0.1

Comment: Have you installed the matching root UI app that asks the user if the app is really allowed to get root permissions?

Comment: i am not trying to give root access to any app im just running 'su' in the terminal of adb, and random app is open in phone, even home screen.

Comment: `su` on Android usually works the way I have described. So you need the UI app the su binary tries to contact.

Comment: may I know which OS are you using it??

Comment: as per the guide also, am using kingroot, and android 6.0.1